# Found an unspecified JVM Bytecode (0xe2) in java class file

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode, opcode, jvm-bytecode

I'm recently developing a program which can analyze a java class file. After running the program this was it's output:
[image: program output 1]
[image: program output 2]
[image: program output 3]

```java
class test_1 {

    public static String a = "Hello World";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int j = 0;
        for(int i = 0;i<10;i++) {
            System.out.println(a);
            j = j + j*j +j/(j+1);
        }
    }
}
```

I got a bytecode 0xe2 which is not specified in jvm specification 14. What does 0xe2 do??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program is outputting every byte as-if they are bytecode instructions, ignoring the fact that many instructions have parameters, so they are multi-byte instructions.

E.g. your program is incorrectly outputting the constructor as follows:

```java
2a: aload_0
b7: invokespecial
00: nop
01: aconst_null
b1: return
```

If you run `javap -c test_1.class`, you will however see:

```java
0: aload_0
1: invokespecial #1   // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
4: return
```

The number before the colon is the offset, not the bytecode. As you can see, offsets 2 and 3 are missing, because the [`invokespecial`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se14/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.invokespecial) instruction uses 2 bytes for parameters, which is documented:

> **Format**
>
> ```
> invokespecial
> indexbyte1
> indexbyte2
> ```

> **Description**
>
> The unsigned `indexbyte1` and `indexbyte2` are used to construct an index into the run-time constant pool of the current class ([§2.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se14/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.6)), where the value of the index is `(indexbyte1 << 8) | indexbyte2`.

With the 2 bytes being `00` and `01`, index is 1, so the bytecode instruction is as `javap` showed: `invokespecial #1`

If you then look at the constant pool output, you'll see that constant #1 is a `methodref` to the `Object` no-arg constructor.

Your specific question is related to bytecodes `a7 ff e2`, which is not 3 instructions, but the 3-byte instruction for [`goto`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se14/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.goto):

> **Format**
>
> ```
> goto
> branchbyte1
> branchbyte2
> ```

> **Description**
>
> The unsigned bytes `branchbyte1` and `branchbyte2` are used to construct a signed 16-bit branchoffset, where branchoffset is `(branchbyte1 << 8) | branchbyte2`.

Meaning that `ff e2` is `branchoffset = 0xffe2 = -30`, which means that instead of

```java
a7: goto
ff: impdep2
e2: (null)
```

You program should have printed something like:

```java
a7 ff e2: goto -30
```

Answer (score 2):

You fail to account for multibyte opcodes. From [the reference for goto](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html), the format is:

```
goto
branchbyte1
branchbyte2
```

> The unsigned bytes branchbyte1 and branchbyte2 are used to construct a signed 16-bit branchoffset, where branchoffset is (branchbyte1 << 8) | branchbyte2. Execution proceeds at that offset from the address of the opcode of this goto instruction. The target address must be that of an opcode of an instruction within the method that contains this goto instruction.

`goto` is 0xa7, and it should be followed by 2 bytes that denote the branch location, making the instruction 3 bytes wide. Your code ignores this, disassembling 1 byte, then treating the next 2 bytes as valid instructions, which they aren't.